# Custom file types

Tags: files

I created a custom file type (to add documents and images). And in my content type, under allowed file types, I only checked my custom file type.
However, when I trying to upload a file, it is giving a choice to select "document" or "custom file type".  I don't want to have that choice. How can I prevent that choice menu from showing up ?

I can't disable "document" because it's used in other content types.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: What do u mean by custom File Type.. ?

Comment: I went here : "structure/file types/add file type"  and created a new file type in addition to core ones like "document" and "image"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is a support request to make file type in file field configurable, see https://www.drupal.org/node/2538102